# Are XSD type definitions validated at compile time?

Tags: eclipse, xsd, wsdl, xsd-validation

In one of my projects, I used to have a WSDL element defined as having length of 20:

```
<xs:element name="LastName" type="mns:String20Type" />
```

Where *String20Type* is defined in an internal XSD:

```
        <xs:simpleType name="String20Type">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="20" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
```

To increase the length of that element, I changed *String20Type* to *String40Type* **without adding a type definition into the schema** and rebuilt:

```
<xs:element name="LastName" type="mns:String40Type" />
```

The build completed successfully without any error, warning, complaint or hint of any type.

Why?

How did the system know what `String40Type` is?

Comment: It seems to me that your build didn't perform any validation of the schema.  That won't happen until you actually TEST your application.  This isn't checked at compile time, this is performed at run-time.

Comment: Oh wow. So this looks like it's pointing to an exposure as the ability to find errors at build/compile time is normally preferable to finding them at run time. I just found the right-click `validate` menu item on WSDL's editor window in Eclipse... Thanks.

Comment: But unfortunately, that `validate` operation doesn't complain either... ideas?

Comment: Hmm... sounds like either Eclipse is not validating it properly or you have that type defined... somewhere.  I use LiquidXML and Altova XML Spy.  I suggest you try those specialized IDE packages and have them validate it and see where the error lies.  They have free trials so give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will look at the tools you suggested. For the record, I followed the instructions at http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-validate-wsdl-using-eclipse.html but they yielded the same result. So perhaps the next step is to try `LiquidXML` and/or `Altova XML Spy`.

Comment: @mastashake57 Your 2nd guess found to be the correct explanation: I have that type defined elsewhere (in that long WSDL file), far from the String20Type definition and I just didn't see it. Furthermore, if I use a truly undefined type (e.g. `String101Type`), `JAXB` will fail the build, issuing an *"undefined simple or complex type 'mns:String101Type' at line 69 column 6 of schema file..."* If you post this as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Good man.  Can't tell you how many hours I have spent building custom XSD only to have some rogue type bite me in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:

Hmm... sounds like either Eclipse is not validating it properly or you have that type defined... somewhere. I use LiquidXML and Altova XML Spy. I suggest you try those specialized IDE packages and have them validate it and see where the error lies. They have free trials so give that a shot.

Comment: Actually, I didn't need these packages as Eclipse WPT's `Validate` was doing its job all this time: These type have been defined all that time except that I didn't know that because the WSDL file is very long and those type definitions are not grouped together for intuitive navigation. All is well now. Also, the answer to the subject line question is: **Yes! XSD type definitions are validated at compile time -- at least if you use [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding).**